# svn-- how to check remote logs without updating

Tags: svn, version-control

Using SVN, if I am on version 100. remote is on verson 110, when I do svn log, I can only see history up to 100. to see revisions 101-110, I need to do an svn update.

Is there a way to see those revisions without svn update?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `svn log <repo url>` to show remote history

Answer (score 2):

You will need to do a `svn log URL` instead of just a svn log. `URL` will be the URL of where you checked it out. `svn info` can give you that information.

Answer (score 2):

Just run the following:

```
svn log `svn info |grep ^URL|cut -f2 -d" "`
```